# Using aspx page as partial view in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views, aspxgridview

I want to use aspx page as partial view in MVC 4. For doing that , I have to inherit it from

```
    "System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>"
```

In this way,  I can not use the code behind (.cs) file. I am using Gridview server control so I have to include code behind for CRUD operations. can u suggest something for this problem ???

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to get the response of the aspx page and then insert it into a div element:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "location/of/aspxpage.aspx",
}).done(function ( data ) {
  $("#divElement).text(data)
});
```

You may have to do something funky to get the html displaying correctly - take a look at http://api.jquery.com/html/ for some help with that